# How to import project in Adobe Flash CC?

Tags: flash, import, project

How can I import project files into Adobe Flash CC?

**Here Is The Image Of Project Files Help:**

[image]

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash-builder/articles/sharing-projects-flashbuilder-flash.html check this URL

Comment: _picture of files/folders_ **+** _"How can I import project files into Adobe Flash CC?"_ **=** means nothing!!... Which of those `.as` files are you trying to import? Are you getting errors? Did you try making a new project and writing code like `import xyz;` etc? Anyways from a quick guess... I think you should open `~project.fla` then check in **properties** (ctrl+F3) to see if `main` is listed as document **Class** (if yes, then click the icon next to Class name, it looks like a pencil icon, to edit the Class). The code of the Class can accepts imports etc...

Comment: **note** This is low-quality question. Writing just one sentence is best for sites like Google search. [**Improve**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it & also [**tell us**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40459975/edit) what you've tried (maybe helps us to understand what you mean exactly). If you're not sure how to open files in Flash CC or how to use this found code, then start with basic beginner tutorials using your own code & test project files first.